# What is meant by fermionic and bosonic "modes"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, fermions, bosons, grassmann-numbers

The paper [The Dirac quantum automaton: a short review](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0031-8949/2014/T163/014014) ([pdf](http://www.qubit.it/research/publications/scripta_dirac.pdf)) starts off by stating:

> The starting point for the construction of space–time and the physical laws therein is an unstructured, countably infinite set, $G$, of local **Fermionic modes**.

I have seen in other papers mention of **bosonic modes** as well. Searching google doesn't give any definition. I understand fermions are quark/electrons/etc., and bosons are photons and such. However, I only have basic undergraduate physics experience. So my only sense after a bit of digging is that the word "mode" is sort of casually used when talking about the different types of wave functions that can occur, but I am not sure.

What is meant by the word ["mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode) in "fermionic modes" and "bosonic modes"? Is there a standard definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The terminology of a *mode* of a free quantum field $\phi(x)$ comes from writing it as a Fourier transform, often also called *mode expansion*:
$$ \phi(\vec x) = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\left(a(\vec p)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec x\cdot\vec p} + b(\vec p)^\dagger\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\vec x\cdot\vec p}\right)$$
where for a spinor or vector field there are additional factors in there that don't play a role here. The crucial question is whether the objects $a$ and $a^\dagger$ (and likewise $b$ and $b^\dagger$) commute or anticommute, since they are the creation and annihilation operators for the particle (resp. antiparticle in the case of $b$) associated to the field.

If they commute, the corresponding particle is a boson - you can pile up arbitrarily many particles into the same state just by applying the creation operator many times. Then, the operators are *bosonic modes*. If they anticommute, the corresponding particle is a fermion - applying the creation operator twice just gives zero, so you can't ever have more than one particle in the same state. Here, the operators are *fermionic modes*. They are "modes" because the Fourier transform splits up a classical oscillation into its pure-frequency modes, so by analogy, we also call the objects it produces when applied to a quanutm field "modes".

In a slight generalization, one calls any collection of creation/annihilation operators bosonic or fermionic modes according to their commutation relations, regardless of whether they arose from a quantum field or were just given in some other way.

Answer (score 3):

The term mode is used to define a particular state of a system and may refer for instance to its spin, wavevector, polarisation, charge etc. If we wanted to create a boson at position $x$ with an up-spin and with wavevector $k$, we may use the field operator $\hat{a}^\dagger(x, k, \uparrow)$ on the vacuum state $\vert0\rangle$.

The most clear distinction between fermionic and bosonic modes are that the field operators describing the former obey anticommutator relations, whilst the later obeys commutator relations. These ensure the Pauli-Exclusion principle and the symmetrisation of the wavefunction respectively.